# Split XML element's names into multiple names

Tags: xml, xslt, nodes, element

I want to transform this XML format

```
<CTP>
    <name>ABSA bank</name>
    <BAs.BA>bank|sector|issuer</BAs.BA>
    <altIDs.altID_label_altSystem>ABSB_BBG|ASB_Reuters</altIDs.altID_label_altSystem>
</CTP>
```

to this format, so I can use it in an integration project while migrating from one system to another.

```
<CTP>
    <name>ABSA bank</name>
    <BAs>
        <BA>bank</BA>
        <BA>sector</BA>
        <BA>issuer</BA>
    </BAs>
    <altIDs>
        <aldId>
            <label>ABSB</label>
            <altSystem>BBG</altSystem>
        </aldId>
        <aldId>
            <label>ASB</label>
            <altSystem>Reuters</altSystem>
        </aldId>
    </altIDs>
</CTP>
```

My main problem is how to split these element's names into multiple elements.

How could I do that?

Comment: Welcome to SO :-) We are not a code-writing service. Please show your effort by editing your question, and ask for concrete help for your code.

Comment: Dear Stefan,
the main problem was spliting the element name,  i did my research but i cant find smtg similar.

Comment: Sorry @KhalilKalaany it's not about research but about code. You practially **must** have code to get an answer about that code. Questions "I need code to ..." are practially not allowed, see [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: it is my first time on SO, i just need to split these elements in multiple elements, can u help me with it? @StefanHegny

Comment: Sure, if you show your code, but you seem to prefer discussing...

Comment: I added your comment's clarifications to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The searchterm to get your work done is **tokenize**.

**XSLT 1.0** recursive template, search `tokenize xslt 1.0` on SO.

**XSLT 2.0** use function `tokenize`, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-tokenize

To get the name of an element you can use `name()`.

Now you "just" have to code it. Split after `.` and `_` to create you desired result.

*[describe your question with words, helps as well, cause is there a case like 'a|b|c' stored in 3 instead of 2 child elements?!]*